# Why do larger companies put little text in webpage and then add it all in the title of the page?

Tags: title, homepage

I have read all over not to got over 100 characters in a title tag but I see large companies in my trade add all the text they have on the page in the meta title tag?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If they do, then they are damned silly for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is you cannot go beyond 70 characters. Anything above is ignored by google. If you are referring to big sites like amazon then user does it as they have no idea of SEO. The other big sites does not have enough time to set metas of each product individual like 100,000 products, who will set the metas? Either they have main keywords in first 70 character or they just dont care.

Usually the big brands dont care much about these things as they are ranking higher based on their brand authority.

Comment: 70 characters with spaces.

Comment: You can go above 70/100 chars and G will occasionally rank/display words that come after the 70th char for certain queries. We do it all the time for certain ecom long tails. There is no "penalty" for having long titles/metas/etc unless it's something like a shopping feed with a certain char limit for fields. As long as it's not keyword spam, and it sounds natural, then do the long titles. Pro Tip: SEO reports will always tell you the opposite of what I just said in order to justify their own existence.

Comment: May be it shows occasionally but never uses it a ranking factor, At max i have seen is 70 - http://www.6dglobal.com/sites/default/files/new-title-tag-1.png
Yes agreed there is no penalty for have long meta title or description.

Comment: Yes indeed it will only display 60-70ish amount of characters, but my thought was that it will occasionally sort keywords that are far beyond that limit, concat it into a title, and spit it out visually. So if you have bananas starting at like the 90th char, you may find yourself lucky and see bananas in SERP title well within 70. G does the same thing for meta tags.